# Can I Inherit from a custom Spider In Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I was creating a new project in Scrapy and I have a Spider like it:

File: **spiders/customspider.py**:

```py
import scrapy

class CustomSpider(scrapy.Spider)
    name = 'CustomSpider'

    def start_requests(self):
        pass
        # exec code
```

Then I created a new Spider like this:

File: **spiders/otherspider.py**

```py
import scrapy
from customspider import CustomSpider

class OtherSpider(CustomSpider)
    name = 'OtherSpier'

    def start_requests(self):
        super().start_requests()
```

But I am getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CustomSpider'

I can't find any help with this on documentation, can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct? You shadow the `CustomSpider` import with the class `CustomSpider` in `otherspider.py`

Comment: Sorry i typed wrong....

Comment: in otherspyder.py the class is OtherSpider not CustomSpider

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you update your question with your exact use case and the full stack trace?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error too. Your code contains at least one syntax error (missing colon in line 4 of file `otherspider.py`). And I'm wondering about the correctness of the error message you mentioned: Does it really mention `CustomSpider`, or `customspider`? Please copy paste your exact code and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Scrapy, but it seems your question is not really about Scrapy but about importing modules in general.

Besides some syntax errors in your code, the problem is in the following statement:

```py
from customspider import CustomSpider
```

Change it to:

```py
from .customspider import CustomSpider
```

or

```py
from spiders.customspider import CustomSpider
```

This assumes that `spiders` is a module, and the working directory of your Python application is one directory higher.

Alternatively, if the directory `spiders` is in your Python path, it should also work with the code you originally posted (if other syntax errors are fixed). However, I don't recommend that as a solution.

Comment: Thanks `from .customspider import CustomSpider` it worked the third option i already tested and doesn't work